# How do I find the equation for any given function?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

If I am given a graph with labeled points, and I’m asked to find the equation that represents the given function, how can I do so? Just by looking at points it would be nearly impossible, and trying to find an approximation is even harder.

Comment: “Lagrange Interpolation” would be a search subject which is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad area known as regression (don't need the equation to go through all the points) or interpolation (need the equation to go through all the points). You often have some *a priori* idea of what shape of function you're after, in which case you can use a regression technique like least squares to fit your model (the *a priori* idea) with the actual data. Good idea to plot the residuals (model minus data points) to see if there's any systemic issue with your fit.